# ExecutorService's ThreadPool workers threads won't invoke autowired member variable methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a class named `WatermarkEventProcessorService`, which contains a few autowired member variables. The `WatermarkEventProcessorService` is being passed into a FixedThreadPool as a task.

The problem is, the ThreadPool worker threads are not invoking the `WatermarkEventProcessorService`'s autowired variables' methods. As soon as an autowired member's method is invoked, the worker thread just stops processing.

Below is the method that creates the ThreadPool:

```
 public void processWatermarkEventObjects(List<WatermarkEventObject> waterEventObjectList) {    

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        for (WatermarkEventObject watermarkEventObject : waterEventObjectList) {
            executor.submit(new WatermarkEventProcessorService(watermarkEventObject));
        }

        executor.shutdown();
    }
```

Below is the `WatermarkEventProcessorService`:

```
@Service
public class WatermarkEventProcessorService implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    private WatermarkEventObject watermarkEventObject;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationAPIService apiService;

    public WatermarkEventProcessorService(WatermarkEventObject watermarkEventObject) {
        this.watermarkEventObject = watermarkEventObject;
    }

    private boolean prismIdExists(WatermarkEventObject watermarkEventObject) {

        return watermarkEventObject.getPrismId() != null && watermarkEventObject.getPrismId().length() > 0 ? true
                : false;
    }

    public ApplicationRecord findApplicationRecordByPrismId(String prismId) {

        System.out.println("Inside findApplicationByPrismId");
        // Prism Id Exists in Table: Application?
        // Call RESTful Web Service to retrieve Application record by Prism Id from
        // MySQL database.

        System.out.println("about to invoke apiService.getApplicationByPrismId()");
        ApplicationRecord applicationRecord = apiService.getApplicationByPrismId(prismId); //doesn't get invoked for some reason...
        System.out.println("returned from apiService.getApplicationByPrismId()");

        return applicationRecord;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting Processor thread.");

        // Validate that PrismId exists, else write to error log file, for now.
        // TODO: Please note that we will need to look up MOTS info & create new
        // Application.
        if (prismIdExists(watermarkEventObject)) {

            System.out.println("within the if block");
            // Gets the application record for the given prism id, or creates
            // a new application record in the database if we dont have one
            ApplicationRecord appRecord = findApplicationRecordByPrismId(watermarkEventObject.getPrismId());
            System.out.println("Returned from findApplicationByPrismId");
        }

        System.out.println("Completed Processor thread.");
    }
}
```

When I run the application, it executes just fine, but the last print statement reached is "about to invoke apiService.getApplicationByPrismId()".  The following log statement -- "returned from apiService.getApplicationByPrismId()" never gets output, nor is an exception ever thrown.

I've also added a print statement within the very beginning of the `apiService.getApplicationByPrismId(prismId)` method, but it also never executes. This indicates that the method is never really invoked:

Below is the method that is not invoked (but should be):

```
@Cacheable("applications")
    public ApplicationRecord getApplicationByPrismId(String prismId) {

        System.out.println("inside getApplicationByPrismId"); //never gets printed
        ApplicationRecord applicationRecord = null;
        ApplicationResults resultList = new ApplicationResults();
.
.
.
}
```

Below are the relevant console logs:

`Starting Processor thread.
within the if block
Inside findApplicationByPrismId
about to invoke apiService.getApplicationByPrismId()
Starting Processor thread.
within the if block
Inside findApplicationByPrismId
about to invoke apiService.getApplicationByPrismId()
Starting Processor thread.
within the if block
Inside findApplicationByPrismId
about to invoke apiService.getApplicationByPrismId()`

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Spring beans are beans that are basically managed by Spring framework.

`@Autowired` and other annotations have affect only(make sense only for) the spring beans.

Being managed by Spring means that Spring by itself creates the objects (by calling `new`)

But this is not what happens here in the code snippet:

```
 for (WatermarkEventObject watermarkEventObject : waterEventObjectList) {
        executor.submit(new WatermarkEventProcessorService(watermarkEventObject));
 }
```

Here `WatermarkEventProcessorService` is created by the application itself, so Spring doesn't know its a bean and hence doesn't make any autowiring on it

In terms of solution:

Note the you already pass the instance of `WatermarkEventObject` despite the autowired annotation put on the corresponding field in the class `WatermarkEventProcessorService`
So why not remove `@Autowired` altogether and just pass an additional parameter, makeing this class non-spring managed at all.

If you need this class to be managed by spring consider using Scope Prototype Scope and create objects like this upon request, with some kind of provider.

Comment: Thank you -- I've removed the `@Service` annotation from the `WatermarkEventProcessorService` and removed the `@Autowired` annotation from the member `WatermarkEventObject` variable too, but am still seeing the same behavior (I can't invoke the other autowired items). I need to invoke these autowired items, so I'll need to have this class be handled by Spring -- how can I modify the class to do this? (using Scope Prototype, etc)?

Comment: As long as all dependencies of WatermarkEventProcessorService (in this case 2 dependencies: watermarkEvenObject and apiService) are spring managed and you supply them as constructor arguments it should work...

Answer (score 2):

You should pass object created by spring container to allow spring manage your dependencies:

```
@Autowired
WatermarkEventProcessorService watermarkEventProcessorService; //injection by field for brevity

public void processWatermarkEventObjects(List<WatermarkEventObject> waterEventObjectList) {    

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    for (WatermarkEventObject watermarkEventObject : waterEventObjectList) {
        executor.submit(watermarkEventProcessorService);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
}
```